# How to do comparison test when the numerator is a polynomial?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Sometimes comparison test can be used to determine the summability of

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{n^2}{(n+1)^p}
\end{equation}
for some power $p$ and I have no problem with this case.

But suppose I want to understand the summability of the infinite series

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{(n+c)^p}{n^2}
\end{equation}

where $c \geq 1$. What is a possible approach to determine for which value of $p, c$ this series of summable and not summable?

I am tempted to just ignore $c$ and look at $p$, if $2 - p \leq 1$, then it is not summable. But I don't know how to make this more rigorous (except expanding the numerator using pascal's triangle relationship; is there a better way?)

Comment: The order of magnitude of the general term is $n^{2-p}$. More precisely, there are constants $C_1, C_2$ so that for all sufficiently large $n$, $$C_1n^{2-p} \le \frac{(n+c)^p}{n^2} \le C_2n^{2-p}$$. You could try to prove this statement.

Comment: Do you know the *limit* comparison test?